# Odds Calculation PHP

Tags: php

[image]So I have a database that needs to output our profit of betting on each game. I want to output what the user would make if they bet $1 on each game, but I also want to show what the user would make if they were to bet $5 on each game. The odds are entered in two columns OddsNumerator and OddsDenominator. So if the odds were 5/6 to win. 5 would be in the OddsNumerator column and 6 in the OddsDenominator column.

Heres what I tried, but this does not come up with the right profit.

```
$data40 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(oddsnum / oddsden) FROM stats WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND winloss = 'Win'");
$info40 = mysql_fetch_array($data40);
$onedollarwins = array_sum($info40);

$data41 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(oddsnum / oddsden) FROM stats WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND winloss = 'Loss'");
$info41 = mysql_fetch_array($data41);
$onedollarloss = array_sum($info41);

$onedollarprof = $onedollarwins - $onedollarloss;
$onedollarprof = round($onedollarprof,2);
```

How can I add up all the profits? Here is the website, but it outputs wrong profits: http://tipmypicks.com/stats.php

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Can you provide some sample data from the stats table?

Comment: If a record has an oddsnum of 5 and oddsden of 6, what is the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Group by id
```

`Group by` shall sum by the columns and distinct by the game ID (id column)
therefore sums all the results per game.

You should consider using the PDO class in order to maintain persistent connection with the database (if you not using cache or need real-time values)

```
$data40 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(oddsnum / oddsden) FROM stats WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND winloss = 'Win' Group by id");

$info40 = mysql_fetch_array($data40);
$onedollarwins = array_sum($info40);

$data41 = mysql_query("SELECT sum(oddsnum / oddsden) FROM stats WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND winloss = 'Loss' Group by id");

$info41 = mysql_fetch_array($data41);
$onedollarloss = array_sum($info41);

$onedollarprof = $onedollarwins - $onedollarloss;
$onedollarprof = round($onedollarprof,2);
```